# Can you run a raw MySQL query in Django without a model?

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I am still learning Django and I'm just now getting into connectors to MySQL. What I'm trying to figure out is how I would go about querying a db/table that I am not creating with a model in Django.

Do I have to recreate the table as a model in order to have it talk to Django? If so, would that basically mean just recreating my structure with a model then importing my data to the new table?

Sorry if this is a goofy question, I appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: You should be more specific as to what you want to do. Maybe you didn't read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/legacy-databases/) about how to use a legacy database? But if you don't tell us what's in your database and how you're going to use it, it's hard to answer.

Comment: @dirkgroten Sorry for the lack of details. As of right now, it's just a testing database with a table made from an imported csv. At this point, I just want to SELECT * FROM test_table basically. Does that help at all or do you need more info? The goal is to be able to query the db and return all rows based on a user's name.

Comment: The answer below tells you how to perform a raw query. But it doesn't sound like you're the right track here. Why wouldn't you create a model based on what's in the csv, then let django create your table, and **then** import the csv into the table managed by Django? That way you get all the benefits of the Django ORM, which returns a proper python object rather than a raw database row.

Comment: The main reason is that the csv is only a test environment, I should have specified that.. sorry. The true db environment will actually be created from a data migration coming from a separate Postgres db. Another team is handling that so I can only do so much with that process. The legacy link you sent me works fine though! Seems like it will do what I need for now.

Comment: "a data migration coming from a separate postgres db". Sounds like you'll also have a new db in production (and not necessarily use the legacy db directly, except as source of data). If I were you I would still let Django manage the db and make the migration in such a way that the legacy data gets imported into the new, managed, db.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, you can query the database table without model by using connection cursor

```
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_sql(self):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name where id=1")
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    return row
```